# how to pass current variables through session in PHP

Tags: php, html, session

PHP session problem:

I am using session to pass some varaiables from one page (index.php) to another page (result.php). The values are asked by user to enter and once submit button is clicked result.php page should open and show the summary of input data.

```
'//index.php
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form" name="form" onsubmit="window.open('result.php', '_blank');return true;" >

Enter Your Email Here:    <input name="email" id="email" type="text" placeholder="your.email@example.com"  pattern="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?" required title="must be your.email@example.com"   />

Input file: <input type="file" name="file" id= "file" maxlength="90" required/>

cutoff: <input type="text" name="cutoff" placeholder="0.005" maxlength="60" />

<input  type="submit" name = "submit" id="submit"   value="Submit"/> </form>'
```

Retrieved information -- emailid, file and cutof, are further used to run perl script using shell_exec. In order to run the complete program, these valuse should be present in result.php page. For variable passing, I used php sessions.

```
<?php 
 //session name in index.php
session_id('testsession');
session_start();
//pass variables email; file and cutoff
$_SESSION["email"] = $_POST['email'];
$_SESSION["file1"] = $filename;
$_SESSION["cutoff"] = $cutoff;
?>
```

And in result.php, the values are recieved as:

```
<?php
//start sesstion
session_id('testsession');
session_start();
echo session_id();

//values recieved by session parameter

echo '<br> email : '.$_SESSION["email"];
echo '<br> File  : '.$_SESSION["file1"];
echo '<br> cutoff : '.$_SESSION["cutoff"];
?>
```

*Questions and problem*

1. is there better way to handle passing variables to different page?
2. **The main problem in this script is that everytime session values recieved by result.php is from the previous session.**
   for example: in index.php file:

email -- n.n@example.com

file -- "test.txt"

cutoff -- 0.002

then in result.php will get

email -- 0

file -- 0

cutoff -- 0

---

but next time if i update again

in index.php

email -- a.a@example.com

file -- "95test.txt"

cutoff -- 0.52

result.php will show

email -- n.n@example.com

file -- "test.txt"

cutoff -- 0.002

**How to take care of session values?**
may be this problem is due to redirecting the page to result.php, any help or suggestion is welcomed.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered simply sending these values within the url?

Comment: You are setting the session ID before the session has been started. For clarity of the data being handled I find it easier to unset the session variables once I have finished with them. That prevents the data getting confused. If you're redirecting the page anyway wouldn't it be simpler to point the form at result.php and handle the data there?

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, i tried session_id after start and unset the session variables, also I tried to redirect the page to result.php. but nothing seems to work. it simply doesnot pass the current value. is there any other way I can handle this problem?

Comment: I can add some more information to the problem: if I put form action="result.php" will not pass the updated values however if I dont put action="" and check for the result.php that shows me the correct values. any idea why that could be??

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but wasn't it session_name instead of session_id?

```
<?php 
//session name in index.php
session_name('testsession');
session_start();
//pass variables email; file and cutoff
$_SESSION["email"] = $_POST['email'];
$_SESSION["file1"] = $filename;
$_SESSION["cutoff"] = $cutoff;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but it is session_id not session_name. Is there any other suggestion that could help improving this code.